# SQLite for a RESTful web service

Tags: .net, sqlite, server

Is SQLite suitable for a RESTful web service? It would handle a website with a moderate traffic (about 10 million requests per month). From what I've read SQLite is very underestimated and can be really performant. Is it performant enough to handle this with ease?

Edit: I am using .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with SQLite isn't performance per se, but specifically performance with simultaneous queries. For just `SELECT` queries it could very well handle that kind of load, but if there are more than a few `UPDATE` queries it'll struggle. Something like [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org) would be a much better choice, and it's easy to set up with most distributions and with packages for most platforms.

Comment: I have read that stackoverflow is using .NET as well, but they went with SQL Server. Is PostgreSQL a better fit? Or it doesn't really matter?

Comment: SQL Server is really great too, but it has a complicated license structure. Postgres is Free both as a license and dollar cost.